# Finding the shortest path between a number of nodes (not just distance)

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, graph, networkx, path-finding

I am trying to find the shortest path that travels through specified nodes in a graph (A -> B -> C instead of just A -> C). Currently, my code will return the shortest path rather than going through all specified nodes.

Code:

```
from networkx import DiGraph
from networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths import multi_source_dijkstra

graph = {'c1': {'c2': 4, 'L1': 3},
         'c2': {'c1': 4, 'c3': 3, 'L1': 2.5},
         'c3': {'c2': 3, 'L1': 2},
         'L1': {'c1': 3, 'c2': 2.5, 'c3': 2}}

# Build the graph
G = DiGraph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from(((source, target, weight)
                           for source, d in graph.items()
                           for target, weight in d.items()))

# Find shortest path (using Dijkstra algorithm)
#result = shortest_path(G, source='c1', target='c3', weight='weight')
result = multi_source_dijkstra(G, sources=['c2','c3'], target='L1')

print(result)
# result: (2, ['c3', 'L1'])
```

Library and function I am using: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.multi_source_dijkstra_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.multi_source_dijkstra_path

I noticed networkx have two traveling salesman functions, but neither of them can return the path, only the distance so I don't think I can use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make multiple calls of `shortest_path`, one for each subpath you need. So when the request is A->B->C, then find the shortest path from A to B, and the one from B to C and concatenate the two results.

`multi_source_dijkstra` does something different: it finds a path from one of the source nodes to the target node.

Comment: One issue here - you should be aware the paths found this way can backtrack (cross the same edge twice).  If that's okay for your application, then this is the correct thing to do.  If that's not okay, then you'll need something different.